# Increasing php array by 1 inside jQuery each function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm struggle to find an answer for this so was hoping to hear from the community.

```
$('.slick-dots button').each(function(index) {
    $(this).html('<?php echo $headings[0]; ?>')
});
```

Within the above .each function, I am trying to increase $headings[0] by one on each loop.

Hopefully I'm missing something pretty simple and I've not gone down an impossible route?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: You're going to get the usual "Don't mix Javascript and PHP" comments here. Incrementing a PHP (server-side) array in a Javascript (client-side) loop isn't something you can do.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis looks like I'm going about this the complete wrong way. Any thoughts on a good route to take starting fresh with the goal of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Not sure if I agree with choice of "duplicate". It tells why it can be done, but doesn't offer a real solution. This is probably more helpful to the OP and future readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Jay Blanchard has marked this as an 'exact duplicate of an existing question'. Perhaps we have different ideas of what 'exact duplicate' means?

Comment: @Nick maybe you could request your php array via ajax and process the response accordingly

Comment: Unfortunately I'm really not familiar with AJAX. I have however resolved the problem by running: <script>headings.push('<?php the_sub_field("heading"); ?>');</script> inside the php loop to a JS variable outside of it. Perhaps that will get me torn apart at StackOverflow, I just needed something that functioned.

Answer (score 1):

Because the PHP runs before the page loads `$headings` won't receive the data you are trying to pass to it